# How to send e-mails to a list of e-mails on a spreadsheet?

Tags: python, email, outlook

I need to send an e-mail to some clients using python. All their e-mails are on a spreadsheet.

The code I have, send the e-mail only to the last line on the spreadsheet. But I need it to send to all the e-mails, individually.

What can I change in my code so that it sends e-mails to everyone?

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd

# integrating outlook
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

# creating an email
email = outlook.CreateItem(0)

ler = pd.read_excel ('D:\Projeto Zurich/email_list.xlsx')
# setting the e-mail
for index, linha in ler.iterrows ():
    email.to = (linha["EMAIL"])
    email.Subject = "Hello," +  (linha ["NAME"])
    email.HTMLBody = """
    <p>Hi, there!</p>
    """

    email.Send()
    print("Email Enviado")
```

[That´s how is my spreadsheet:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTCpM.png)

Comment: This *looks* as if it should send emails to everyone.  Where is the tracing you did to show its operation?  Insert appropriate `print` commands to diagnose the problem.  Also, please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: You haven't yet isolated the problem: it could be a failure reading the file, iterating through the file, or in sending emails.  Again, make MRE and trace the operation.

Comment: Hi, Prune! I made some changes to my question, please let me know if that´s right. I read the article about the MRE, but how can I know if it's a failure reading the file, iterating through the file, or in sending emails. When I play the code, it opens a message on outlook requesting permission to send the emails, I allow it, and it sends an email only to the last one on the spreadsheet. I also added a picture of how my spreadsheet looks like. If I need to add other information, please tell me. And thanks for the help <3

Comment: "how can I know" says that you need debugging lessons -- this is not a Stack Overflow function.  See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.  Also see [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to make this in two steps:

1. You need to get the email from the sheet
2. Then, you make a loop on your list of emails and send email

For example, the email are in the first column and subject in the second:

```py
# Reading an excel file using Python
import xlrd
# Give the location of the file
loc = ("path of file.xlsx")
# To open Workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for i in range(0, 100): # "100" allowing the number of email you have
  # For row 0 and column 0
  email = sheet.cell_value(0, i)
  subject = sheet.cell_value(1, i)
  send_email(email, subject)

def send_email(mail_address, subject):
  # ADD HERE YOUR CODE FOR SENDING YOUR EMAIL
  email.to = mail_address
  email.Subject = "Hello," +  subject
  email.HTMLBody = """
  <p>Hi, there!</p>
  """
  email.Send()
  print("Email Enviado")
```

Comment: Don't forget to modify the `send_email` function, and to adapt the gathering of email, subject.
Plus, you need to change the the path of the file

Comment: Your arbitrary requirement of 100 -- or even knowing in advance -- breaks the program.
Also, why does the refactoring matter?  The original does a loop of read-extract-send.  You replace this with read-extract-accumulate and the a sending loop, but you never explain what problem the original has, that you fixed.